# moqui customer/supplier, order/request

Tags: erp, moqui

New to Moqui, have some questions:

1. In an organization, it is quite common that one sales person take care of several customers, and not allowed to view other sales person's customers. Same as buyer to suppliers. After some study, I suppose the correct way is to create party relationship AE(Account Executive) between the sales person and customer or buyer and supplier, after creating party(customer or supplier) and party role?
2. When one sales person log in and find his/her customers(party), since more than one entities are involved(party relationship, party...) use view entity or entity find and data filter, econdition?
3. While reading order entities and request entities, for quotation, there is status id of order requested in order entities, what is the difference of doing quotation by order entities or request entities? or, should I use order entities or request entities to do quotation?
   Appreciate if someone can give some directions.

Answer (score 0):

The Sales Opportunity is related to the prospect/client through the *SalesOpportunityParty* entity.

You also relate it to the sales person(s) and any other parties who may be involved somehow in the opportunity through this entity, using roles, and fromDate, toDate to define the nature and period of their involvement.

There is recently a new field added to the SalesOpportunity entity, 'accountPartyId' - I presume this also can be used for convenience.

All relationships between entities are already pre-defined for you. There are 'seed' roles also pre-defined if you look at the Party entities, which you can use, or you can define your own if you need to.

To query your data, look at the PartyViewEntities.xml in Mantle USL for inspiration - you will need to define your own view entitities at this stage to work with the Sales Entities. It is made very easy for you to do this.

You would likely use the Order entities rather than Request entities. The Request entities are for handling RFIs, RFPs etc. I.e. Requesting a bid or quote, or a response (to a 'requirement'). Refer to Len Silverstone's Data Model
Resource Book, or the second half of David Jones 'Making Apps with Moqui' book for more insight into this.

(Also note you will need to do some work with the SalesOpportunityStage entity to define and use your own opportunityStageIds to the same degree you can use statusIds in the rest of the framework.)

Hope that helps.